# why doesn't mysql create the pid?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

mysql starts fine, everything is working as expected, but there is no pid file where my.cnf says it should be, the .sock is there

this is the relevant section of my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

but

```
/var/run/mysqld# ls
mysqld.sock
```

ps aux...

```
ps aux | grep mysql
mysql    23990  0.1  4.4 887340 75904 ?        Ssl  17:25   0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Again, everything works, but i need the pid so that [God](http://godrb.com) can monitor it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Old bug from 2008 where someone got the PID created after another restart or stop+start: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41067
- Normally I see an error when that file is not there ...
- But a possible solution (1st shutdown mysql)...

  ```
  cd /var/run/mysqld/
  sudo touch mysqld.pid
  sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld.pid
  ```

  Unless you want actually have it created by the deamon (but I would consider it a bug).

Comment: -.- yup that did it, restarted twice and it did update the file, thanks

Comment: oh so the 1st one worked? Weiiiiiiiiird :D

Comment: no creating the file for it worked, didn't even need to stop it, just restarted and it used the file (i've restarted before the file and no change, so for some reason it couldn't create it)

Comment: noup, something's up, gone again, maybe even my god config

Comment: Check your mysql script. is there anything special in it? Like "su mysql -c "exec /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld" &"?

Comment: i think it was my god config file that was deleting it

Comment: FWIW, I had to change the ownership of the parent directory to be `mysql` as well to get this working:  `sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`.